# For loop is taking very long time to run

Tags: excel, vba

In Macro, I am using the below code to autofill the columns. The Excel sheet has nearly 90k rows it's working but it's taking more than an hour to complete. Is there any other way, other than **For Loop**.

Can someone guide me in this?

For reference I have attached a sample snapshot in the link for autofilling method.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Wu9.png][1]

```
irow10 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
     
For i = 1 To irow10
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) = "" Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i - 1, 4)
End If

Next
```

Comment: If the code works then you should be posting on Code Review.

Comment: Best option would be to use Powerquery for that (search for FillDown). Or at least use an array to do the data manipulation instead of writing to each cell individually.

Comment: @SolarMike its taking very long time more than an hour to run a macro.
There must be simpler way which runs it faster other than for loop which am not aware of. thus seeking for a help.

Comment: Go to Code Review, it is exactly what they do: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Also are you doing this on a cheap laptop with 4gig memory or a beast with 64gig? Makes a difference.

Comment: Try caching things: 1) save ActiveSheet to a local variable before the For loop in order to avoid invoking it 3 times per iteration. 2) Prefer using WorkSheet.Columns over WorkSheet.Cells to work with a limited range. 3) Eventually, save in a local dictionary or list all discovered/assigned values, to avoid getting them from the previous cells. Additionally, you are not using Value property at the right side of the assignment inside the loop. And.. test whether the culprit is the initial Find or the subsequent For!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I alread wrote: try powerquery first.

If you want to keep with VBA than you should use an array to do the "transformation" and then write back to the sheet

```vb
Sub fillDown()

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

Dim rgData As Range
Set rgData = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 4).Resize(lastRow)

Dim arrData As Variant
arrData = rgData.Value

Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To lastRow
    If arrData(i, 1) = vbNullString Then
        arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i - 1, 1)
    End If
Next

rgData.Value = arrData

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That helped. Sorry since i have less reputation couldnt help with the vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple Excel formula for this?

I have just created an Excel sheet, containing the following data:

```
Col1 Col2
A       1
B       2
C       <BLANK>
A       1
B       2
C       <BLANK>
A       1
B       2
C       <BLANK>
...
(up to 97345 cells (you mentioned 90k))
```

Then, I selected all cells in the next column and wrote the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),A2,B2)
```

After that, I pressed Ctrl+ENTER for entering that formula in all selected cells.

I got following results:

```
Col1 Col2        Col3
A       1           1
B       2           2
C       <BLANK>  C
A       1           1
B       2           2
C       <BLANK>  C
A       1           1
B       2           2
C       <BLANK>  C
...
```

This was done in a matter of seconds!

I had also recorded my actions, and I ended up with such a macro (after some editing):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("C2:C97345").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),RC[-2],RC[-1])"
End Sub
```

Executing this macro also does not even take a second.